# Error while Verifying Domain in AAD

Tags: dns, azure-active-directory

I followed [Quickstart: Add a custom domain name to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/add-custom-domain)  to verify my custom domain but still experiencing difficulties. I owe a domain (something like www.example.com with the only difference is mine is not 'example') purchased at GoDaddy.com.
If I try to verify that domain and specify its name (in AAD portal) as www.example.com then I can successfully complete the verification, but if I use the name example.com (without www) - I am seeing an error saying

> Unable to verify domain name. Ensure you have added the record above
>   at the registrar 'MyDomainNameIsHere.COM', and try again in a little
>   while.

I employed [nslookup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490950.aspx) to make sure the TXT record was added, I also followed the section [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/add-custom-domain#troubleshooting), non of those 3 cases apply to me:

- waited for few hours
- made sure with nslookup that the dns record is
  correct and exists
- there is no existing domain with that name

Why does it work if I prefix it with **www** and doesn't without it? Do I need to make some changes at GoDaddy?

I need that custom verified domain to add AAD users associated with their emails at my domain, for instance, User1@example.com; User2@example.com and so on. That doesn't work when I verify the www option complaining that example.com is not verified domain but doesn't complain if I try to create a user User1@www.example.com and I cannot do that because there is no corresponding email address.

Comment: Could you show what the TXT record looks like?

Comment: Usually, it should be verified. Ensure you'v added same TXT record as Azure showed in portal. I did a test, it verified quickly.  Show your TXT record or all records in GoDaddy, I believe we can help you resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you add **www**  in Azure or Records of TXT in Godady?

Comment: This is the TXT record: MS=ms27578875. As I mentioned I made sure that I am able to see this record by leveraging nslookup, so, it is 100% there. I have just tried to verify the same domain in my other tenant and I saw there another error for first few minutes: **Could not find the DNS record for this domain. DNS changes may take up to 72 hours to propagate. Please try again later** then, in 5-10 minutes I again started seeing that above mentioned error which looks to me like Azure indeed was able to find the dns record but failed for some other reason.

Comment: As for whether I added **www** or not - as I mentioned in original question I was able to Verify the Domain in Azure Portal if I prefix it with www but I am not I am unable verify it because of the aforementioned error.

Comment: I have just done an experiment: registered another domain with godaddy and also setup corresponding email and then I repeated **the same set of steps in the same tenant** and was able to Verify that Domain... so, something looks wrong with that specific domain which I tried to verify first. It is sad that Azure Portal, as well as MSOL PowerShell (I also gave it a chance), just display very generic completely not-actionable errors in that case.